# Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:jdbc.hive

Tags: jdbc, sqlalchemy, hive, apache-superset

I'm trying to build an application with superset, I've installed superset, Hive on my Hadoop cluster and I'm trying to connect to my Hive data base with super set but every time, I try to do so I receive this error:

> ERROR: {"error": "Connection failed!\n\nThe error message returned
> was:\nCan't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:jdbc.hive"}

Once I click on the "`Test Connection`" button.

Please does any one have a solution for this? Here's a screen shot of the problem

[image]

Comment: When looking for more info I came across: https://github.com/apache/incubator-superset/issues/2632 Did you try this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes I've already found that link and I have tried the proposed solution, but I still have the same issue.

Comment: I got this working by using the following connection string: `hive://<hive_server>:<port>`. Essentially you can omit the jdbc bit and get it working.

Comment: Are you install pyhive?

Comment: @Joseph When I do this I got this error: _Cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory_ I've tried every thing but nothing works !

Comment: @Mahdi yes I have the latest version of pyhive installed

Comment: @fadhlounanis I'm guessing you have not installed some shared library. Most likely a *-dev* package thats listed in the superset installation instructions.

Comment: @Joseph no that can not be the issue, I'm sure I've Installed all the packages listed in the superset installation instructions, also I have installed Druid on my hadoop Cluster wich contains an installed version of superset and I had exactly the same problem !

Comment: I also tried to connect superset with hive and installed pyhive successfully, it can show tables once I clicked "Test Connection" but raised timeout error when query anyone of hive tables. The query issued is "2018-01-17 16:53:26,746:INFO:pyhive.hive:SELECT SUM(`zhima_avro`.`id`) AS `sum__id`
FROM `default`.`zhima_avro`
LIMIT 50000". The hive thrift server error is "FAILED: ParseException line 1:9 cannot recognize input near 'SELECT' 'SUM' '(' in describe statement". Anyone can tell me how to config it workable?

Comment: @Joseph, thanks man, its working

Answer (score 6):

For me in HDP with ambari:

```
cd /usr/hdp/3.1.4.0-315/superset/bin/
./pip3.6 install sasl
./pip3.6 install thrift_sasl
./pip3.6 install pyhive
```

Test:

```
./python3.6
>>from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
>>engine = create_engine('hive://localhost:10000/default')
```

without errors.
Restart superset and work

Comment: does this work with newer versions of python?